# Declaration Merging not Working in Angular 2 Project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack-2

I am trying to implement a custom RxJS operator as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035242/3865524). Here are the relevant snippets in my application:

rxjs-extensions.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

function restrictToCommand<T>(this: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    console.log('works');
    return Observable.empty()
}

declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
    interface Observable<T> {
        restrictToCommand: typeof restrictToCommand;
    }
}

Observable.prototype.restrictToCommand = restrictToCommand;
```

consumer.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import '../../rxjs-extensions';
...
export class MyComponent {    

...

    private load(): void {
        Observable.of(1).restrictToCommand();
    }

...

}
```

When `load()` is called, I receive the following exception:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./MyParentComponent class MyParentComponent - inline template:2:4 caused by: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.of(...).restrictToCommand is not a function
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.of(...).restrictToCommand is not a function
    at MyComponent .load (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3530:1), <anonymous>:45:75)
    at MyComponent .ngOnInit (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3530:1), <anonymous>:63:14)
    at Wrapper_MyComponent .ngDoCheck (/AppModule/JobsPanelComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:22:53)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_MyParentComponent 0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/MyParentComponent/component.ngfactory.js:62:32)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3185:1), <anonymous>:301:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3185:1), <anonymous>:394:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_MyParentComponentt_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/MyParentComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3185:1), <anonymous>:301:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:3185:1), <anonymous>:394:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:1708:1), <anonymous>:136:20)
```

I am using Angular 2, Webpack 2, and TypeScript 2.0.3.

Comment: It works fine for me with TypeScript 2.2.1 and 2.0.3. You might want to add some logging to `load` to see exactly what `Observable.prototype.restrictToCommand` is at that point.

Comment: `console.log(Observable.of(1).restrictToCommand);` shows me that `restrictToCommand` is undefined...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple RxJS installations? Without knowing your project structure, it's not clear exactly what the `../../` entails. The code in `rxjs-extensions.ts` looks fine, so if after importing it the `Observable` prototype doesn't contain `restrictToCommand`, my guess is that there are multiple RxJS modules floating around. Run `npm list rxjs` to see if it's able to find more than one module.

Comment: On a hunch, I just tried adding `import './rxjs-extensions';` to my `app.module.ts` file, in which I was already importing `./rxjs-imports`. This seems to have fixed the issue! Now to understand why... :)

Comment: Once you've figured out what's going, please post a [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, I had to add `import './rxjs-extensions'` to my `app.module.ts`, where I was already importing `./rxjs-imports`, a file that contained all of the RXJS operators that I was using in my application.

Unfortunately, I still don't fully understand what is happening. I will update the answer if I ever gain a clearer understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Observable.of operator?

In your rxjs-extensions module,

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Comment: I import `of`, in addition to any other operators I want to use, from `rxjs-imports`, which is in turn imported in `app.module.ts`. This was a suggested approach in a Pluralsight video to optimize the RxJS bundle size.