# In Typescript, create extension method for class that from library

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I want to add some method to existed class that come from library.

Known some basic type like `String`, `Element` can extension via `interface` and add it's `prototype`.

```
interface String {
 extFunc():Function;
}

String.prototype.extFunc = function () {
  //blabla
};

"a".extFunc();
```

I also find the way to add extension method of `Observable<T>`.

```
declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    foo: String;
  }
}
Observable.prototype.foo= "bar";
console.log(Observable.of("a").foo);
```

But when i try to do same thing to NavController(an lib from ionic), it will override entire NavController to the interface that i declare.

```
declare module 'ionic-angular' {
  interface NavController {
    replace(page: Page): Promise<any>;
  }
}
navCtrl.replace(...); //ok
navCtrl.push(...); //original function => "not exist"
```

Does anyone know what is best way to add extension method to those class? thanks~

**Edit:**
There is actual code

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

import {GuidePage} from '../guide/guide.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  pageName = "home";

  // navCtrl is come from angular2's Dependency Injection,
  // it may not suitable to extend NavController
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  gotoGuide(): void {
    //wanna replace this
    this.navCtrl.push(GuidePage).then(() => {
      let index = this.navCtrl.getActive().index;
      this.navCtrl.remove(index - 1);
    });

    //with this custom extension method 
    //this.navCtrl.replace(GuidePage);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034248/combine-rxjs-operators-into-new-operator-using-typescript/42035242#42035242) and solve my question with the following code.

In `polyfill.ts`

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-util';
// the class we wanna create extension method
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller';
// ionic provide this as NavController
import {NavControllerBase} from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base';

// add extension method on both class via interface
declare module "ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller" {
  interface NavController {
    // replacePage?: typeof replacePage;
    replacePage(page: Page, data?: any);
  }
}
declare module "ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base" {
  interface NavControllerBase {
    // replacePage?: typeof replacePage;
    replacePage(page: Page, data?: any);
  }
}

// define extension method 
function replacePage(this: NavController, page: Page, data?: any): Promise<any> {
  return this.push(page, data).then(() => {
    let index = this.getActive().index;
    this.remove(index - 1);
  });
}

// finally add this function to the class that ionic provide
NavControllerBase.prototype.replacePage = replacePage;
```

usage:

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController)
foo(){
    this.navCtrl.replacePage(HomePage, {nextPage: OtherPage});
}
```

This way to add extension method on other class, wish this help someone after.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is how to extend a class, but your code shows interfaces.

How to extend a class from a library:

```
class LibraryThing {
    // this is a class from a library
    doSomething(){
    }
}

class MyThing extends LibraryThing {
    // here you can add your own methods to the existing class
    doMyThing(){
    }
}
```

Now you can create a MyThing instance which will have all the library methods and your own methods:

```
let t = new MyThing();
t.doSomething();
t.doMyThing();
```

If you want to use interfaces you can simply implement them. You can implement existing library interfaces and complement that with your own interfaces

```
interface LibraryInterface {}
interface MyOwnInterface {}

class CoolThing implements LibraryInterface, MyOwnInterface {
    // this class uses methods from the library interface and your own
}
```

You do not need prototype when working with typescript.

**EDIT**

I have not tried if this works, but instead of passing the navcontroller in the constructor, you can pass your own class that extends navcontroller.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {CustomController} from '../mystuff/customcontroller';    
import {GuidePage} from '../guide/guide.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  pageName = "home";

  // here we receive our own CustomController
  constructor(public navCtrl: CustomController) {}

  gotoGuide(): void {
    this.navCtrl.myOwnCustomStuff();
  }
}
```

In CustomController you can import Navcontroller and extend it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular'

@injectable()
export class CustomController extends NavController {
}
```

I haven't tested if this is allowed for an ionic component though!

You also have to register your own new injectable as a provider for angular DI, follow the steps in [your link](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectable)

Comment: Thank for answering, but the class i want to add method is come from angular2's Dependency Injection, in other word it's come from constructor(). see there for more detail.
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectable

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question with your actual code, including the dependency injection.

Comment: Ok! i have post my actual code, thank for your advice.